# Phase shift in clamper circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, diode-clamp, clamp, falstad

I'm trying to simulate this clamper circuit in [falstad](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html):

[image]

But there's a phase shift in the output voltage of [my circuit](https://github.com/Sbrjt/Sbrjt.github.io/files/12795076/circuit.txt). Is this expected? Am I doing something wrong?

[image]
[image]

Can someone please explain?
(I'm an absolute beginner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is expected. The circuit contains a high pass filter. You can read more about it at many sites like this one:

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_3.html

Capacitors are reactive components - they will not allow an instantaneous voltage change across them. This is the reason there’s a phase shift.

This time dependence is described through the capacitor equation (derivatives) or with complex numbers - a capacitor’s impedance has the j term (sqrt(-1)). Complex numbers are used for circuits because they can be used to describe both both magnitude and phase info.